# Parsing a string to a hash

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I have a string:

```
<https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=2&per_page=5>;
rel="next",
<https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=1&per_page=5>;
rel="first",
<https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=8&per_page=5>;
rel="last"
```

So the format is

```
(<val>; rel="key")*
```

And I want to parse that to a hash with the following format:

```
next => https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=2&per_page=5
first => https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=1&per_page=5
last => https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=8&per_page=5
```

In Java I would use a regex pattern to extract each key => value pair and put them into a map. The pattern would be something like:

```
<([^>]++)>;\s*rel="([^"]++)"
```

Which would give me the key in the second match group and the value in the first. Would the same approach be the best way to achieve this is Perl, or is there something snazzier I could do?

P.S. the reason I'm using Perl rather than Java is that the server doesn't have Java.

Comment: What do you mean by "snazzier"? Perl's regex support isn't exactly lacking, and it's really not uncommon to use them in Perl.

Comment: @Mat I know Perl's regex support is excellent. But I also know that Perl has many other string processing features. I was just wondering whether there was a more builtin way of processing a double-delimited list to a hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `split` the string on a "," and then use a `map` to create the hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=2&per_page=5; rel="next", https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=1&per_page=5; rel="first", https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=8&per_page=5; rel="last"';

my %hash = map { 
    my ($v, $k) = $_ =~ /\s*([^;]+);\s*rel="([^"]+)".*/; 
    $k => $v;
} split ',', $str;

foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
    print "$key => $hash{$key}\n"
}
```

output:

```
first => https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=1&per_page=5
next => https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=2&per_page=5
last => https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=8&per_page=5
```

#### update

With the new string you could do:

```
$str = q(<https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=2&per_page=5>; rel="next", <https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=1&per_page=5>; rel="first", <https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=8&per_page=5>; rel="last");

my %hash = map { 
    my ($v, $k) = $_ =~ /<([^>]+)>;\s*rel="([^"]+)".*/; 
    $k => $v;
} split ',', $str;
```

to get the same result.

Comment: This is also an interesting approach, +1. I didn't realise you could coerce a list into a hash like that!

Comment: @Boris glad you like it :) Personally I prefer this approach (using `split` first) as I'm a bit scared of complicated regular expressions!

Comment: I think the regex is (almost) identical - the difference is between using external or internal iteration on the collection. Yours also explicitly splits on `,`. This is a little more failfast however, so it's what I ended up using.

Comment: @Boris thanks for accepting my answer, I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 6):

My first inclination was to split the string on commas and work with the three substrings, but it is probably better to use a global match ina  `while` loop.

This should do what you want. (Perl is by far the better tool for text processing like this!)

**Update** I've just realised that your choice of markdown discarded the angle brackets and newlines. Is this more appropriate? I assume it's a multi-line string?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = <<'END';
<https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=2&per_page=5>;
rel="next",
<https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=1&per_page=5>;
rel="first",
<https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=8&per_page=5>;
rel="last"
END

my %data;
while ($str =~ / < ([^<>]+) >; \s* rel="([^"]+)" (?:,\s*)? /xg) {
  $data{$2} = $1;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%data;
```

**output**

```
{
  first => "https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=1&per_page=5",
  last  => "https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=8&per_page=5",
  next  => "https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=2&per_page=5",
}
```

Comment: I went to @Tom's solution in the end as it's more failfast - if the pattern's not found in the individual strings then you get an error.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: You can pick whichever one best suits your needs, but neither Tom's code nor mine is set up for detecting errors because you didn't say you wanted it. My version will find all matches in the string that it can and just ignore any malformed data, while with Tom's you get an `Use of uninitialized value` warning if the regex doesn't match at all and `$k` is set to `undef`. That isn't proper error handling, and there are ways it could give invalid results without any warning.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string='https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=2&per_page=5; rel="next", https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=1&per_page=5; rel="first", https://gitlab.me.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=8&per_page=5; rel="last"';

my @array=split /,/, $string;
my %hash;

foreach(@array)
{
   if($_=~/(.*?);\s*rel\=\s*"([^"]+)"/)
   {
      $hash{$2}=$1;
   }
}

print "$_ =>  $hash{$_}\n" foreach(keys%hash);
```